# SpriteMaterial with alphaMap

Tags: three.js

When I try to use alphaMap with THREE.SpriteMaterial: I am getting this message 
THREE.SpriteMaterial: 'alphaMap' is not a property of this material.
Is there any way to clip SpriteMaterial with alphaMap?
Thanks

```
 const imgTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(`logo.jpg`);
                        const circleAlphaMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(`alpha.png`);

                        const material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: imgTexture, alphaMap: circleAlphaMap, alphaTest:0.5 });
                        const sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
                        sprite.scale.set(12, 12);
                        obj.add(sprite)
```

Comment: You can patch the material with `.onBeforeCompile` or write your custom shader material.

Comment: Support for alpha maps: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/17675

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a `.png` file with transparency? You can see that's the method they employ [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_sprites).

When you click on the bottom-right (`< >`) icon, you can see the source code, and it's just a transparent png set to the `map` property.

```
var mapB = textureLoader.load( "textures/sprite1.png" );
var materialB = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {
    map: mapB,
    color: 0xffffff,
    fog: true
} );
```

Comment: There are thousands of jpg files. I can't convert them to png

Comment: Ah, then you'd probably have to write your own custom shaders in GLSL. It's a bit more complicated, since you'd have to learn the language if you don't know it already, but [here's an example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles) of how you could accomplish this in ThreeJS.

Comment: @SERG You could always draw your images to a canvas and apply that to the material. It may be easier than the other options.

Answer (score 1):

Just an option with patching the material (can't say how correct it is):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 1);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var spriteMat = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(`https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg`),
  alphaTest: 0.75
});
spriteMat.defines = {
  USE_ALPHAMAP: ''
};
console.log(spriteMat)

spriteMat.onBeforeCompile = shader => {
  shader.uniforms.alphaMap = {
    value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(`https://threejs.org/examples/textures/sprites/circle.png`)
  };
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `#include <map_pars_fragment>`,
    `#include <map_pars_fragment>
     #include <alphamap_pars_fragment>
    `
  );
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `#include <map_fragment>`,
    `#include <map_fragment>
     #include <alphamap_fragment>
    `
  );
}

var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMat);
scene.add(sprite);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. I would prefer to write a custom shader, like Marquizzo said.